# How to filter an array in a MongoDB document based on query on collection?

Tags: mongodb

Suppose the following collection of documents that include an 'user_id' field and an array of ids that this user follows

```
{"user_id": 1 , "follows" : [2,30]},
{"user_id": 2 , "follows" : [1,40]},
{"user_id": 3 , "follows" : [2,50]},
... large collection
```

I would like to filter out from "references" the numbers that don't exist in the collection as an id. Think about it as a data cleaning procedure, where follows to users that don't exist anymore need to be deleted. Example output from input above:

```
{"user_id": 1 , "follows" : [2]},
{"user_id": 2 , "follows" : [1]},
{"user_id": 3 , "follows" : [2]},
... large collection
```

I thought about a projection with a "$filter", but I can't find an expression for checking that a document with that id exists in the whole collection (as $filter seems to be limited to the current document).

Then I tried to aggregate a set of all ids to use an $in condition, but that failed miserable due to the size of collection (too large object error).

Thought about unwinding, but I'm hitting the same rock: can't find an expression to $match or $project that answers the question "Does this value of 'follows' exists as an 'id' in the collection?"

The only other thing I see doing the filtering client side with a few independent queries, but wanted to check first with the community if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a `$lookup`, like this:

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'users',
  localField: 'follows',
  foreignField: 'user_id',
  as: 'follows'
}
```

This will produce a result like `{ user_id: 1, follows: [ {user_id: 2, follows: [1, 40] } ] }`. Then you should be able to get the result you want with `$addFields` (to map `follows` to `follows.user_id`).

```
$addFields: { follows: "$follows.user_id" }
```